# pm unistall error: unknown option: --user

Tags: android, adb

Estoy tratando de desinstalar "Processor", debido al troyano "Fadeb.J". Me recomendaron desinstalar en  mi usuario el paquete del "Processor", que es "com.android.amazon.adv", pero al ejecutar en adbshell el comando

```
uninstall -k --user 0 'com.android.amazon.adv'
```

me arroja el error "pm uninstall error:

> unknown option:--user.

¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo desinstalar el paquete? Muchas gracias por la atención.

Answer (score 0):

**Desinstalar aplicación o paquete mediante ADB**

Primeramente ubica mediante la linea de comandos el archivo adb.exe que se encuentra dentro del directorio donde se instalo el android Sdk, directorio platform-tools

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ejemplo:

```
cd C:\Users\jorgesys\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
```

aquí ejecutarías el proceso `adb.exe`, te recomiendo usar `cmd package uninstall` en lugar de únicamente  `uninstall` ::

```
adb shell cmd package uninstall -k  --user 0  '<paquete de aplicación>'
```

en el caso de la aplicación que deseas desinstalar sería:

```
adb shell cmd package uninstall -k  --user 0  'com.android.amazon.adv'
```

al realizar satisfactoriamente este proceso, se eliminará la aplicación y obtendrás en la linea de comandos el mensaje:

```
Success
```

---

Puedes usar también

```
adb uninstall -k  'com.android.amazon.adv'
```

pero con este método la información de caché se quedará aún eliminando la aplicación.

http://adbshell.com/commands/adb-uninstall

Comment: Saludos. Todavía no logro desinstalar el troyano. Tengo una duda sobre la recomendación. al principio me recomiendas que ubique el adb.exe. Ese ejecutable no hace nada en mi Laptop, no abre ventanas ni nada. Yo abro una ventana usando "SHIFT + Botón derecho" y ahí uso los comandos "adb devices" y "adb shell". Si coloco el comando que me recomendaste ($adb shell cmd package uninstall -k -- user 0 com.android.amazon.adv) el comando no hace nada.

Comment: ¿Será que estoy escribiendo mal el comando, o que no puedo modificar ese programa (Processor)? Me estoy volviendo loco con esto, ya hasta llevé el teléfono a configuración de fábrica, a ver si se me facilita el proceso. El troyano sigue ahí, como me habían comentado.

Comment: @Gerardo, estando dentro del directorio /platform-tools ahi es donde ejecutas adb .... , al menos te debe mostrar un mensaje al ejecutarlo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no le estas asignando la ubicación. 
Haz esto:

1- Abres el adb de platforms-tools

2- Escribes `adb devices` 
y presionas enter (es más que nada para corroborar que lee tu dispositivo)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3- Escribes `adb shell` 
y presionas enter para ingresar al dispositivo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4- Escribes `pm list packages | grep 'samsung'` luego das enter 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

5- Escribes `pm uninstall -k --user 0 'com.android.amazon.adv'` luego das enter y ya
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, donde dice 'samsung' debes poner la marca de tu dispositivo sea hwawi, motorola, etc. Espero que te haya servido